# Find $ S_{20} $ if $ \frac{ a_{n} +2}{2} = \sqrt{2S_{n}} $ for all integer n

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define $ a_{n} $ is a sequence and all terms of $ a_{n} $ are positive. $ S_{n} $ is the summation of the first n terms. If $ \frac{ a_{n} +2}{2} = \sqrt{2S_{n}} $ for all integer n, then find $ S_{20} $

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{a_1+2}{2}=\sqrt{2a_1} \Leftrightarrow (\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{2})^2=0$$

Thus

$$S_1=a_1=2$$

Next

$$\frac{ S_n-S_{n-1} +2}{2} = \sqrt{2S_n} \Leftrightarrow (\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{2})^2=S_{n-1}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{S_n}=\sqrt{S_{n-1}}+\sqrt{2}$$

Let $T_n=\sqrt{S_n}$.

Then $T_1=\sqrt{2}$ and

$$T_n =T_{n-1}+\sqrt{2}$$

Can you find $T_{20}$?

Comment: @DavidH Ty, fixed...

Answer (score 0):

$S_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=S_{n-1}+a_n=S_{n-1}+2(\sqrt{2S_n}-1)\Rightarrow$ $S_{19}+2(\sqrt{2S_{20}}-1)=S_{20}$. Also we have $S_{20}-S_{19}=a_{20}$. Adding these two we get 
$2\sqrt{2S_{20}}=a_{20}\Rightarrow S_{20}=\frac{a_{20}^2}{8}$.

Comment: Isn't $S_{20}-S_{19}=a_{20}$?

Comment: Yer you are right I edit it thanks